# codeigniter Pass array from view to controller

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

View:
`user_data` coming from the controller (Database middleware values)

```
<?php
      $ID['IDS'] = array_column($user_data, 'ID');
      print_r($ID);
     // print_r($ID)=Array( [IDS] => Array([0] => 0 [1] => ABCD [2] => EFG ) )?>
```

Controller

```
 $postData = $this->input->post();
 $payment_code=$postData['IDS'];

$payment_code=$ID;
$postData = $this->input->post();
echo "<b>Name :</b> ".$postData['IDS']."<br/>";
 $this->load->view('Demo/code_Send_data', ['code_key'=>$payment_code]);
```

[ Questions ]
can not see value in code_Send_data view
how to pass array value from view to controller
Is my `<?php echo form_open('login/send_validated_Code_To_final',$ID['IDS']); ?>`  syntax correct ??

Comment: are u posting this `$ID['IDS'] = array_column($user_data, 'ID');` by using form?

Comment: `echo "<b>Name :</b> ".$postData['IDS']."<br/>";` this will print u `echo Name Array`

Comment: or your question is controller to view?

Comment: in your view try this `print_r($code_key);`  u will the result

Comment: pass it like `$this->load->view('Demo/code_Send_data', ['code_key'=>$payment_code, 'id' => $ID]);` and then in view access it like `$id`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send additional hidden input data from the view to the controller, add a third parameter containing the data array (the second parameter is for the attribute, you can leave it empty) :

```
$ID['IDS'] = array_column($user_data, 'ID');
<?php echo form_open('login/send_validated_Code_To_final', '', $ID); ?>
```

Refs : [Form Helper Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)